# Resources on BRST and BV quantisation for local quantum field theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, brst

This is a reference request, to ideally a textbook, monograph, set of lecture notes or lecture videos, on the topics of BRST quantisation and the Lagrangian BV formalism. My constraints are as follows:

1. Minimal use of the path integral formulation when possible, and minimal use of the category theoretical constructions of quantum field theory.
2. Described in the context of local quantum field theory, or provides examples in such a context in $d \geq 2$.

While not mandatory, I would appreciate if the resource referenced or used the viewpoint of gauge theory in terms of principal bundles and their associated vector bundles.

The resource may assume a strong background in the usual physics preliminaries, and a strong background in differential geometry, algebraic geometry, commutative algebra and homological algebra.

Resources I have already considered are:

- [*Quantisation of Gauge Systems*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/069108775X/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1) by Hennaux et al, a very comprehensive book but difficult to distil what is essential and what can be ignored, depending on requirements. Large dependency on previous chapters. Very encyclopaedic.
- [*Quantum Field Theory: Batalin–Vilkovisky Formalism and Its Applications*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08096) by Mnev (or his notes). Maybe the best resource I know of, but rather concise.
- Miscellaneous chapters in books like BBS's [*String Theory and M-Theory*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/string-theory-and-mtheory/0D112662D065F738422C8A6E507545AB) offer an introduction to the BRST formalism, but lack some mathematical generality I would enjoy, and the references to cohomology are brief, à la physicists.

Comment: Aiming for minimal use of path integrals is probably a counterproductive restriction. A short presentation of the BV formalism for toy models given by finite dimensional path integrals is in the JMP article by Albert, Bleile and Froehlich https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.3278524

Comment: Other references that might be useful are the books Kasia Rejzner https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-25901-7 and the one by Costello https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-170

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam If I loosened the path integral restriction, what would you recommend?

Comment: The ones I just gave. I assumed loosening of the path integral restriction already.